# reading all variables dynamically from external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm loading an external javascript file filled only with variables with int or strings or booleans or arrays in them. Something like...

```
varBool=false;
var1="var1";
var2="var2:";
var3="var3";
anothervar3="anotehr var 3";
var5="var5";
testvar2="test var 2";
var7="var7";
var8="var8";
myvar34="myvar 34";
var10="var 10:";

morevars2="more vars!";
morevarshere="more vars here.";
morevars5="more vars.";
morevarsthere="more vars there";
myarray=new Array(1);
myarray[0]="d";
anotherarray=new Array(5);
anotherarray[0]="value 1";
anotherarray[1]="value 2";
anotherarray[2]="value 3";
anotherarray[3]="value 4";
anotherarray[4]="value 5";
```

I've read some questions about accessing these variables from the parent JS by accessing the variable name itself. but the files i'll be loading are going to have different sets of values everytime a new JS would be loaded. Is it possible to get the values dynamically without specifying the exact var name?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you end up deciding?

Answer (score 1):

Create a JSON object to store the data instead. Then you can iterate over the object to get the key/value pairs.

```
var vars = '{"name": "Someone","number": 15,"type": "something"}';

var json = JSON.parse(vars);

for (var key in json){
    console.log(key + ' => ' + json[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming you don't have control over the external javascript files*

All of the variables in your example would be defined in the `global` scope. This means that they get assigned to the `window` object.

You can then access them using either the **dot** or **bracket** syntax:

```
// dot syntax
window.var1; 
// -> "var1"

// bracket syntax
window['var1']; 
// -> "var1"
```

So you don't need to know the exact variable name, you can check to see if the variable is defined on the `window` object and use the **bracket** notation to get the value

Comment: I did not get the impression he did not have access to the external file, just that he wanted to have a master include file for all of his variables. That said, if he had no other option this would be a great solution, but it is worth pointing out for those that don't know, [Global Variables Are _generally_ Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)